# TF31002: Unable to Connect to this Team Foundation server

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

I have a server that the team foundation server is installed on. I can connect to TFS from several computers, but I can't connect to its from my laptop through internet. I can connect to it from web, but I can't via team explorer.

Indeed I can't add server via team explorer in visual studio, and I receive following error.

[image: TF31002 Error message]

I have connected to this server for 3 months. Then I deleted the team project from server and worked offline. Now I want to add my solution to TFS, but I can't connect to it.

Comment: Is it with the same user as on the other computers? Probably it is going to be an issue with rights of the user if it is a different one.

Answer (score 2):

Flushing TFS cache fixed this error for me. To do so;

Delete the contents from the following folders

- C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
- C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

Go to the Visual Studio IDE folder in command prompt and run the following command "devenv /resetuserdata" from the Visual Studio IDE folder.

- Typical location for 64 bit: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE
- Typical location for 32 bit: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE

Also, not sure if it made a difference but I also deleted this registry key;

- KEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage

[Source and more details here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an older version of VS than TFS, make sure you install the forward compatibility packs.